# Can't save VCard using aSmack and Openfire

Tags: java, openfire, smack, asmack, vcf-vcard

I have a problem creating VCard on aSmack. I can see that my VCard has not been saved when I try to load it.

- When I try to load a VCard created by another client, everything works perfectly.
- When I try to load the VCard from a user created on Openfire, I get the following error :

`service-unavailable(503)
 at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard.doLoad(VCard.java:568)
 at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard.load(VCard.java:551)`

- When I try to load the VCard from a user I created with my client, I get the following error:

`remote-server-not-found(404)
 at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard.doLoad(VCard.java:568)
 at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard.load(VCard.java:551)`

To create a VCard from my client, first I log in then I use the following code :

```
VCard userCard = new VCard();
userCard.setField("customField", "yes");
try {
    userCard.save(mConnection);
    Log.i(TAG,"usercard saved "+userCard.toXML()); /* it is displayed! */
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,"An error occured while sending Vcard"+userCard.toXML(),e);
}
```

Before connection mConnection, I added the line `ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard","vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());`

According to this post (http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/34689), it is not possible to modify VCard if we are using LDAP. But I don't get errors when I try to save a VCard, it just doesn't save it !

Does anyone has the same problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be that you need to specify who the vCard you created belongs to:

- for the user currently logged in, use `vcard.load(conn)`
- for any user of your service, use `vcard.load(conn, username)` where `username` should be the full username, i.e. login@host.tld

I tested this code and everything works fine:

```
// Load vCard of logged in user
private void loadVCard(XMPPConnection conn) {
    VCard vcard = new VCard();
    vcard.load(conn);

    vcard.setFirstName("Foo");
    vcard.setAvatar(imageBytes("http://example.com/avatarjpg"), "image/jpeg");
    vcard.save(conn);
}

// Load vCard of give user
// username: ex mylogin@chat.myservice.com
private void loadVCard(XMPPConnection conn, String username) {
    VCard vcard = new VCard();
    vcard.load(conn, username);

    byte[] avatarBytes = vcard.getAvatar();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(username + ".jpg");
    out.write(avatarBytes);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the same using aSmack instead of Smack ? I think my problem might be specific to aSmack

Comment: I've tried with aSmack. It works fine with the currently logged in user. And when you try to change another vCard... it still updates the vCard of the currently logged in user. Which is according to the docs, the right behavior. It's king of confusing but it makes sense that you can't modify the vCard of somebody else than you.